# How can I parse Json in livecode?

Tags: arrays, json, livecode

I am trying to make a weather app using a API provided by http://www.weather.com.cn

I have three elements on my stack, "weatherdata" field, "city"field and a button. The idea is there is a "cities.txt"file saved in the desktop stored the city name with its corresponding code that is identical to the API. Something like this:

```
101010100=Beijing
101010300=Chaoyang
101010400=Shuangyi
101010500=Huairou
101010600=Tongzhou
101010700=Changping
101010800=Yanqing
```

the API is a link: 
`http://m.weather.com.cn/data/(city code.html)` For example if I want the weather info of Beijng the link would be look like:
http://m.weather.com.cn/data/101110101.html

when get into the link, it will provide the weather data in JSON format like:

```
{"weatherinfo":{"city":"西安","city_en":"xian","date_y":"2014年3月4日","date":"","week":"星期二","fchh":"11","cityid":"101110101","temp1":"13℃~3℃"...}
```

And I want my app to gather the info from that, only appear the specific information in corresponding field.

Basically, what I want is when I type Beijing in city field and click the button, the app will replace the (city code.html)part to corresponding city code form "cities.txt". And then the "weatherdata" field will display the information provided by the API in a format that we could read.

So far I copied [EasyJSON](https://github.com/luxlogica/easyjson) into my StackScript. And my button code looks like this:

```
on mouseUp
  put the text of fld "city" into tCityName
  put specialFolderPath("desktop") & "/cities.txt" into tFilePath
  put textDecode(tCityList,"UTF8") into tCityList 
  put lineOffset("=" & tCityName & cr,tCityList & cr) into tFoundLine
  set the itemDelimiter to "="
  put item 1 of line tFoundLine of tCityList into tCityCode
  put "http://m.weather.com.cn/data/" & tCityCode & ".html" into tURL
  put URL tURL into tRawJSON
  put textDecode(tRawJSON,"UTF8") into fld "weatherdata"
end mouseUp
```

However, it is not working, except in the weather data field this showed up:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
window.open("/","_self");
}; 
</script> 
<!-- START WRating v1.0 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://c.wrating.com/a1.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var vjAcc="860010-2151010100";
var wrUrl="http://c.wrating.com/";
vjTrack("");
</script>
<noscript><img src="http://c.wrating.com/a.gif?a=&c=860010-2151010100"width="1" height="1"/>
</noscript>
<!-- END WRating v1.0 -->
</body>
</html>
```

I am really confused and don't know how to fix it, can someone please please help me out?

[Here is my application](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dbttvmbg0e4v9m/WeahterApp.zip?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a temporary glitch. If I run the following script

```
on mouseUp
     put empty
     put url "http://m.weather.com.cn/data/101110101.html" into myData
     put the result into rslt
     put rslt & cr & myData
end mouseUp
```

I get json data in the message box, which can be parsed with EasyJSON. Only once in a while I get HTML code and/or an error code in the result. If that happens, just try again in a few minutes.